# TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building and Inventory Web App and I am facing this error. I am trying to get Username from token to show a custom hello message and show that the user is logged in as someone.

Here is my Views.py that gets Token from localStorage as logged in user:

```
class UserDetails(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserAccountTokenSendSerializer(data=request.data)
        global token
        if serializer.is_valid():
            token = serializer.validated_data['token']
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get(self):
        user_id =  Token.objects.get(key=token).user_id
        details = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        serializer = UserDetails(details, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

```
class UserDetails(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
        )
```

Here is my Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('get-user-token/', views.UserDetails.as_view()),
    path('get-user-details/', views.UserDetails.as_view()),
]
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[15/Jun/2022 19:34:59] "GET /api/v1/get-user-details/ HTTP/1.1" 500 82239
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`.get(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View) takes a `request` parameter as well, even if you do not use it, so:

```
class UserDetails(APIView):

    # …

    def get(self, request):
        # …
        pass
```

I would *strongly* advise, not to make `token` a global variable. The same webserver can be used for another user that thus has not authenticated (properly). Take a look at the [*Authentication* section of the Django REST framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) for more information on how to authenticate and check credentials.

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `UserDetailsView`, instead of <s>`UserDetails`</s>.